# how to work with tesseract and ocr in Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, tesseract

I followed [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-python-tesseract-ocr-on-heroku-bbcc39391a8d) article, I added tesseract_cmd, in code, added Aptfile, but after deployment getting issue:

```
import cv2
import os
class TestingView(APIView):
    def post(self, req):
        print(req.FILES)
        crop_img = req.FILES["ok"]
        print(crop_img)
        file_loc = "media/"
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location=file_loc)
        filename = fs.save(crop_img.name, crop_img)
        crop_img = cv2.imread(file_loc+"crop_12_.png")
        print(os.getcwd())
        f = open("ok.txt", "w+")
        f.write("shiv")
        f.close()
        pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "/app/.apt/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata"
        output = pytesseract.image_to_string(crop_img, lang='hin') #, config=)
        text = "ok"
        return Response({"ok": output})
        # return Response({"ok": text})
```

[image: errors]:

```
PermissionError at /testing/
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/.apt/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata'
```

build_pack and TESSDATA_PREFIX=/app/.apt/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata also added.
any solution?

Comment: did you add file with language `hin` ? As I know as default it should work only with english. And it keeps languages in folder `tessdata`. GitHub: [tessdata](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata)

Comment: ya hin I added in Aptfile

Comment: you assign `tessdata` to `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd`  but `tessdata` is folder not program. `tesseract_cmd` needs path to program `tesseract`, not folder `tessdata`. Even your tutorial use `tesseract_cmd = ‘/app/.apt/usr/bin/tesseract’` to assign program `tesseract`, not folder `tessdata`

Comment: @furas what should I do now? I have to deploy on heroku

Comment: you have to use correct path to tesseract. You can check in termila if you can run `tesseract` and then get its path `which tesseract` or you have to install it first using `apt-get install tesseract-ocr` (or something similar) and maybe also `apt-get install tesseract-ocr-hin`

Comment: @furas I removed  pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "/app/.apt/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata", now it's working

Comment: you can put it as answer and later you can mark your answer as accepted, and few minutes later you can upvote your answer.